# Servlets in karaf/servicemix

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I get the following error when I deploy a simple .war file in karaf/servicemix. Kindly let me know if I'm missing something.

ERROR:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.web.servlet.ConnectServlet not found by JDBCWebDemo [207]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_26]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1619)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:900)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:194)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_26]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.newInstance(RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.java:221)[122:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:1.0.7]
```

The code is given below:

Manifest.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 2 
Bundle-SymbolicName: JDBCWebDemo 
Bundle-Version: 2.3 
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes 
Import-Package: javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ConnectServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ConnectServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>app.web.servlet.ConnectServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConnectServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ConnectServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OSGi bundle most likely need to export the package that has the servlet code, eg in the MANIFEST.MF file you need to have

```
Export-Package: app.web.servlet
```

Comment: Awesome. However, according to OSGi Export-Package definition, "Bundles may export zero or more packages from the JAR to be consumable by other bundles." I have not used the servlet outside of the war and why would it still require this parameter? And why is it I need to export only the servlet, there were other classes which worked just fine without defining in the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Because karaf actually does something with the classname you specify in `<servlet-class>`. It tries to load that class. For Karaf to be able to find that class in your bundle you need to export it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not inside your war, you need to import the right package.

```
Import-Package: app.web.servlet
```

or if it's inside one of your libs in the lib folder you need to make sure all of those jars are included in the classpath:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes, WEB-INF/lib/jar1.jar, ....
```